# Community Health Dashboards

Tags: feature-request, community, data-analysis, site-analytics

This is based on [a recent Meta Software Engineering question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-many-people-are-answering-questions).

---

It would be interesting to expose, to the community, information about community health. The Meta Software Engineering question asked about demographics on who is answering questions - how many people are active in answering questions, what kinds of content (likely by tags, but perhaps using semantic search) these people are answering, what kinds of content (again, by tags but perhaps semantic search) people are asking about, and if the active users align with the popular topics.

However, there are already some existing metrics for high rep users that could also be useful for a health dashboard: questions, answers, accepted answers, up votes cast, down votes cast, page views, visitors. Some of these could be expanded slightly to give some additional health metrics: question closure or deletion, negatively scored posts, time between post and first answer or post and first positive score answer. I'm sure a discovery effort would be necessary to figure out what metrics are likely to be interesting or useful, to both communities and the CM team, on how active, vibrant, or healthy a community is.

I'd ultimately summarize this as a feature request for enhancements to the site analytic tool dashboard to make it more meaningful and useful, which would require some discovery effort from various people at the company engaging with moderators and other "power users" of sites across the network.

Comment: This would be lovely to have but I would put big money on the numbers being so *unflattering* that they would have to be redacted to save face.

Comment: "active users align with the popular topics" Not sure what this means. How do you align with a topic? Also, couldn't some SEDE queries deliver these data? We would need a way to regularly run these queries and update a graph view of the results.

Comment: Related [What makes a community healthy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36858) - for many years the most simple indicator of health (getting out of beta) was questions per day. For big sites like SO one can surely break that down on popular tags or tag families.